# Adding a prefix to each word in a string

Tags: python

Assume I have a following string:

```
s = '100*apple/orange*2-apple'
```

How can I transform this string so I get:

```
s = '100*fruit.apple/fruit.orange*2-fruit.apple'
```

I.e. how to add "fruit." prefix to each A-Za-z word in the string?

Thanks!

What I tried is to do the following:

```
regex = r'\b\w+\b'
list=re.findall(regex,s)
list1='fruit.' + list
```

Finally I substring each element of list found in s by element of list1

Now my question is if there is a morepythonic way to do this?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b', r'fruit.\1', s)`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that's the solution, not a comment. I would post it as an answer

Comment: @JohnSmith I fear it's a duplicate.